# Call to a member function parameters on null when offset exist

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, offset

Why am i seeing this error "Call to a member function parameters on null"

Request->Offset Exist in this line of code `if(isset($request['language']) && ($request['language'] != 'undefined'))`

I believe I am already checking if the parameter has been set before and if it's value is not undefined before proceeding

[image]

```
 try {
            $r = new Request();
            $r['id'] = $this->audit_id;
            $html = $this->APIController->generateHTML($r);



public function generateHTML(Request $request) {
        error_log("generate audit HTML job called");
        error_log("request array here");
        error_log(json_encode($request->all()));
        $languageSelected = 'en';
        error_log($languageSelected);
        if(isset($request['language']) && ($request['language'] != 'undefined'))
        {
            error_log($languageSelected);
            $languageSelected = $request['language'];
        }
        error_log($languageSelected);

        $id = $request['id'];
```

`$request->all()` **value here**
[image]

Comment: Use `$request->input('language')` or `$request->language`; I've never seen or used `$request['language']` in Laravel; that looks like you're maybe trying to replicate PHP's `$_POST['language']` (or `$_GET['language']`, etc.), and that seems to trigger that error.

Comment: @Tim Lewis i have added more information to the original post. When I pass in the request parameter I actually added a new id property to it and I was able to access it using request['id']

Comment: Ah ok, so you're making your own `Request()`; you omitted that from your first version of this question, but that might be important. I'll do some digging and see if I can recreate your issue.

Comment: @TimLewis i added more error log, such as error_log(json_encode($request->all())) which shows {"id":15812} which means that the language parameter is indeed not set. So i am unsure why I am receiving such an error

Comment: Ok, so this is truly bizarre... The error only seems to happen when you call `isset($request['language'])`. If you do `$request['language']`, it returns `null`. It also happens on both `id` and `language`, regardless if you set them via `$r['id']` and `$r['language']`. If you call this `generateHTML` method via a Route directly, then `isset($request['language'])` _doesn't_ trigger that error... This has something to do with passing the Request from another source, i.e. calling `$this->apiController->generateHTML($request)`, but I don't know why.

Comment: As an alternative, the `Request` class has a `has()` method, so you can refactor your `if()` statement to `if ($request->has('language') && $request['language'] != 'undefined')` (or `$request->input('language') != 'undefined')` to better fit Laravel coding conventions) and it should work without errors.

Comment: Will test your suggested solution out, thanks! @TimLewis. You might want to post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as selection if it works

Comment: I would guess that it depends it it's an array of inputs vs a single input, like `$request['params'] = ['variable_name' => 'Whatever'];`, vs `$request['variable_name'] = 'Whatever'`, but again, I don't use `$request[]` syntax directly, so I can't say for sure. And I didn't really answer this, so much as provide an alternative. I will note though, if you use this method via a Route directly, like `Route::post('/generate-html', [YourController::class, 'generateHTML');` (or `Route::get()`) and not `$this->apiController->generateHTML()`, then your posted code works just fine. It's _very_ weird 